# To get xml node value using php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to get the value present in xml node for that I written following code.

The code aim is to get

```
        1.Board value,
        2.Address->City value,
        3.Photo->PropertyPhoto->SequenceId value.
```

Code is:

```
        //some code
       $fsp =  $xml->saveXML();
       echo $fsp; //it's output is given below
       $s = simplexml_import_dom($fsp);
       echo $s->PropertyDetails[0]->Board; 
       echo $s->PropertyDetails[0]->Address->City;
       echo $s->PropertyDetails[0]->Photo->PropertyPhoto->SequenceId;
```

OUTPUT OF echo $fsp is:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <PropertyDetails ID="13953882" LastUpdated="Thu, 09 Jan 2014 01:43:48 GMT">
       <ListingID>188691</ListingID>
       <Board>117</Board>
        <Address>
             <StreetAddress>B LOCAL RD</StreetAddress>
             <AddressLine1>B LOCAL RD</AddressLine1>
             <City>PORT REXTON</City>
             <Province>Newfoundland &amp; Labrador</Province>
             <PostalCode>A0C2H0</PostalCode>
             <Country>Canada</Country>
        </Address>
        <Photo>
           <PropertyPhoto>
               <SequenceId>1</SequenceId>
            </PropertyPhoto>

           <PropertyPhoto>
               <SequenceId>12</SequenceId>
            </PropertyPhoto>

        </Photo>
        <ViewType>Ocean view</ViewType>
```

It doesn't given any output.

Output required is:

```
                 117
                 PORT REXTON
                 1,12
```

Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things I see here.  First of all, your XML is not properly formatted.  Your PropertyDetails tag is not closed.  So close that out, and instead of using a DOMDocument, use the SimpleXMLElement class.

First your XML needs to corrected like thus:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <PropertyDetails ID="13953882" LastUpdated="Thu, 09 Jan 2014 01:43:48 GMT">
      <ListingID>188691</ListingID>
      <Board>117</Board>
      <Address>
         <StreetAddress>B LOCAL RD</StreetAddress>
         <AddressLine1>B LOCAL RD</AddressLine1>
         <City>PORT REXTON</City>
         <Province>Newfoundland &amp; Labrador</Province>
         <PostalCode>A0C2H0</PostalCode>
         <Country>Canada</Country>
      </Address>
      <Photo>
       <PropertyPhoto>
           <SequenceId>1</SequenceId>
        </PropertyPhoto>

       <PropertyPhoto>
           <SequenceId>12</SequenceId>
        </PropertyPhoto>

      </Photo>
      <ViewType>Ocean view</ViewType>
    </PropertyDetails>
```

Notice the last line.

Now use SimpleXMLElement and you will be close to accessing the way you want.

```
$s = new SimpleXMLElement($fsp);
echo $s->Board;
echo $s->Address->City;
$sequence_ids = array();
foreach($s->Photo->PropertyPhoto as $PropertyPhoto) 
    $sequence_ids[] = $PropertyPhoto->SequenceId;
echo implode(',',$sequence_ids);
```

Since  is your root node in the XML, you dont need to access it via ->PropertyDetails[0].  It knows.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First load the xml from the string within your var:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($fsp);
```

apidoc here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php

And then read the tags requested:

```
//board
$boards = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Board');
echo $boards[0]->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
//city
$cities = $doc->getElementsByTagName('City');
echo $cities[0]->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
//sequence ids
$arrIds = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('SequenceId') as $sid) $arrIds[] = $sid->nodeValue;
echo implode(',', $arrIds);
```

This assumes you only have only one listing within your file! Otherwise you have to do the tag-lookups depending on parent-nodes (not on global document).

Hope this helps!